# RDS resolves to public IP from within VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, amazon-rds

I'm working with an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 20.04 and RDS; both are in the same VPC. I've added security groups to allow connections to the RDS from the EC2 instance.

I am having an issue where a ping to the RDS instance from the EC2 resolves to the the public IP instead of the private IP and so the mysql connection fails; the connection succeeds if I use the inernal IP so its not an issue of not being accessible.

I am assuming this is related to some DNS cache but I've tried flushing and still down't work. The commands I've tried are below:

```
sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
sudo /etc/init.d/dns-clean start
```

Any ideas how we can solve this issue? How can the rds endpoint to resolve to the internal IP?

Comment: are you sure that your db subnet is formed from private subnets. can you confirm that.

Comment: Yes, I can connect using the private IP.

Comment: did you tick the option `PubliclyAccessible` true when creating the RDS. I think that is the case

Comment: Yes, but I have other instances that do resolve to the internal IP.

Comment: its not advisable to connect using specific ips, its recommended to connect using the endpoint url. because amazon can change the ip addresses

Comment: I don't connect using IP address in production. I just did it for troubleshooting with the internal IP to verify they can communicate . I use the endpoint and security groups

Answer (score 1):

For improved security, it is better to use `PubliclyAccessible = No`. This will cause the DNS Name to resolve to a private IP that is only accessible from within the VPC. It will also assist with using Security Groups to control access to the database.

Comment: The DNS name will resolve to a public IP only if it's accessed from outside the DB instance's VPC. From inside the VPC it should resolve to the private IP address when it's marked as PubliclyAccessible according to the AWS docs https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.WorkingWithRDSInstanceinaVPC.html#USER_VPC.Hiding  However, it's not clear from the OP's question if their EC2 instance is in the same VPC as the DB or not.

Comment: @talonx Thanks for the correction -- I just tried it myself and can confirm that a database launched with `Publicly Accessible = Yes` will resolve to a private IP within the same VPC. I'll update my answer accordingly.